# A purse is but a rag

Tags: grammar

> A purse is but a rag unless you have something in it.

I read this in chapter 1 of Moby Dick by Herman Melville. Here is a link to the context [Moby Dick, page 14](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/mobydick-14.html#:%7E:text=Herman%20Melville%3A%20Moby%20Dick&text=For%20to%20go%20as%20a,you%20have%20something%20in%20it.)

Here what does but mean? Is it not, which doesn't quite fit the context?

Comment: Please make sure you cite the book, author and provide a link to the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a poetic or formal use of "but" as an adverb meaning ["only" or "just"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/but#:%7E:text=formal-,only%3B%20just%3A,-She%27s%20but%20a) or "merely" or "not more than"

So this can be expressed as "A purse is only a rag ..."

Comment: Thanks. I have found another sentence using but, but this one seems a bit strange with the meanings you suggest above. " for who could tell but what the next morning, as soon as I popped out of the room." Would you say it is the exact use of the meanings above with a hint of playful overuse?